# SSL and php logins

Tags: php, security, openssl, ssl-certificate

I successful configured a self signed SSL certificate and configure it in the MAMP server, now if i type `https://localhost:443/` it will show the certificate, now i would like to configure a httpsdocs (like htdocs) and implement a secure login, can any one help me to run a simple page using SSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can create a htdocs_ssl(by default, this will be the folder name apache searching for https pages) folder for putting our https page ,

thank you all for your support

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer when you figured it out.